# How can I use a service worker to cache the homepage?

Tags: javascript, html, css, service-worker, mobile-website

I'm trying to add a service worker to https://aqua.hyperstage.co.uk/ . The images and CSS files are loading when I turn the internet off (e.g https://aqua.hyperstage.co.uk/views/standard/images/railside_catchpots_1920x1080.jpg) but loading the root URL doesn't work.

In my service-worker.js I have '/' in the array of precached files and when I go to Cache Storage under Application in the dev tools it looks like it has cached the page.

[image: screenshot of devtools]

Does anyone know what I'm missing?